# Problem with a user's screen using a Discord Bot running on Heroku

Tags: heroku, discord.py, screenshot

I have a Discord Bot that captures a desktop screen using `pyscreenshot` and compares the screenshot with a picture. **The bot runs perfectly fine locally for all functions, but has problems with getting access to the user's screen when running it on Heroku.**

I understand that this is due to `pyscreenshot` being a desktop screen-capturer, so nothing is being captured on a server. So, is there workaround such that the server can run the bot and capture a user's screen?

Just in case, the errors from Heroku are as follows:

`2021-02-15T22:26:59.784500+00:00 app[worker.1]: pyscreenshot.err.FailedBackendError: All backends failed!` and
`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: FailedBackendError: All backends failed!`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The function would have to be executed on the user's computer, as if this was able to be ran from the server, taking a picture of the user's screen, it would be unbelievably exploitable.

Comment: @ Kelo I see. I'm only making the bot for my friends so I guess I'll just send them the code. Thanks for the response!